# Setting properties of UI elements without having to restart simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ipad

I have a lot of UI elements on my screen, and I have to tweak their appearance to perfection including the frame, text color, background, color, corner radius, etc. Each tiny tweak means that I have to re-compile the code and restart the simulator - and it can take 5-6 seconds per iteration, which is very time consuming (and annoying) when 100's of tweaks have to be made by trial and error. My question is if there are any techniques to instantly update the properties of each UI element WITHOUT having to recompile the code and relaunch the simulator.

One technique I had in mind is to embed a UIWebView which will automatically download a json from a localhost server that contains all the UI elements and their properties. I would have Grunt Server running on my local machine and it would detect any change made to that json file and cause the UIWebView to refresh and download the new json after every edit. There would be a handler in my code which will set the UI element properties to the new values contained in that json. This way I can just have the simulator and a text editor side by the side and I can see how the changes I make in the json impact the appearance of the UI elements instantly.

Perhaps there are other developers out there who have had the same issue and can share how they overcame this annoying problem. I don't like using nib files - so please don't tell me to use nib files :) Even with .xib files, you still have to compile them.

Comment: So your UI is laid out in code? Not interface builder?

Comment: I hate interface builder. It's bad for source control and merging and you still have to do things programmatically since it doesn't support setting all possible properties. I do everything programatically. I am a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a second little viewController subclass with UISliders etc you can set to do various things, rgba for a colour for example, set up a quick and dirty protocol to push these values back to root viewController and redraw element in question, then pop the second view controller modally to tweak stuff (inside a UIPopover on iPad simulator would probably be easiest.  This could become a nice reusable 'skinning' class that you use in development, just need a tool item or button to trigger it)

Probably NSLog the values as well so when you finalize something you can hardcode or typedef it in